# Generating interatomic potentials via force matching

Tags: reference-request, molecular-dynamics, ab-initio-calculations, forcefields, interatomic-potentials

I am trying to learn best practices for force matching ab initio molecular dynamics (AIMD) data with nonlinear least-squares minimization to generate interatomic potentials for use in classical MD.

I understand the concepts of selecting appropriate reference structures (for the expected classical MD behavior) and fitting to physically-justified functional forms. However, the art of selecting the right weighting factors, the right amount of reference structures, and judging if a set of potential parameters are fit properly appears to be highly open-ended problem with no single solution.

**I was wondering if anyone knows of good resources (or has any advice) on gaining mastery and judgment over this process.**

Comment: What is AIMD? Can you link to some examples of problems like this?

Comment: It stands for ab-initio molecular dynamics

Comment: Would [this work](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/what-is-the-cutting-edge-for-open-source-force-field-generation/1413?r=SearchResults#1413)

Comment: Why would you want to fit using a fixed functional form?